# How to save R plots with enlarged text

Tags: r, plot, png, par

So I am trying to enlarge and save a number of plots in R as png. I have been able to save the enlarged plots themselves, but the text on those plots is still too small. To account for this, I have tried setting:

```
par( ps = 12, cex = 1.33, cex.main = 1.33 )
```

Before calling for:

```
png( "Fig1_resize.png", width=300, height=300, units="mm", res=300 )
```

followed by the plot command - for example:

```
plot( RPCA$sdev^2/sum(RPCA$sdev^2), xlab="Component number", 
     ylab="Fraction of Variance", type="s" )
```

Then I just save that to my computer with:

```
dev.off()
```

The font in the plot that R returns is enlarged, but not the font in the saved plot. How can I save enlarged text plots with R?

Thanks for your help

Comment: If you're not restricted to the png format, have a try with `pdf` and `jpeg`. I sometimes find that the images they save are slightly different. For PDF, there's probably a way to specify the font size in points. That could be a pretty portable solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would start by increasing the base pointsize of the plot. See `?png` and note the details of the `pointsize` argument, which defaults to `12`. Hence I would try:

```
png("Fig1_resize.png", width=300, height=300, units="mm", res=300,
    pointsize = 14)
....
dev.off()
```

and increase the assigned value of `pointsize` until you get something that is acceptable for your needs.